# Vectorized vector construction in R through indexing

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I would like to construct an atomic vector `X` using values from a vector `A`, such that `length(X)>=length(A)`. Furthermore, the values of `X` are indexed by a third vector `B` such that `length(B)=length(X)`. The mapping to construct X is as follows:

`X[i] <- A[B[i]]`

Now, it is clear to me how I would construct the vector `X` in a for loop. My question is: since the `X` is due to be quite large (`length(X) ~ 30,000`) is there a way to vectorize the construction of `X`? That is, apply a blanket function that avoids element by element calculation. I looked into functions such as `sapply` and `mapply`, but I didn't see how I could incorporate the indexing of vector `B` into those.

For example, if:

```
A <- c(20,31,17,110,87)
B <- c(1,1,2,1,1,3,4,3,5)
```

I would expect `X` to be:

```
X <- c(20,20,31,20,20,17,110,17,87)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are trying to do along with the expected output?

Comment: updated with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very simple to vectorise, so you can avoid overcomplicating it with `apply`s or loops etc. - simply use `B` as numerical vector to index the values of `A`.

In your case, using `A[B]` translates to `A[c(1,1,2,1,...,5)]` which is basically saying "return the 1st element of A, the first element of A, the second element of A, the first element of A... the fifth element of A".

```
A <- c(20,31,17,110,87)
B <- c(1,1,2,1,1,3,4,3,5)

A[B]

## > A[B]
## [1]  20  20  31  20  20  17 110  17  87

X <- A[B]
```